# Drawing D3 lines of reading from a JSON

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a D3 project and I am wondering how can I draw lines between two points by reading the data from a JSON document. Document provides 4 Xs and 4 Ys values, I couldn't find a way to do it efficiently and everything I tried just got me errors(code doesn't work). Because it is 15000+ lines and it is impossible me to write the coordinates one by one also it is not a way to create a dynamic program/software.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your container :

```
var svg = d3.select('#container').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 500)
```

Your data :

```
var thisData = {
    x1: 50,
    y1: 50,
    x2: 450,
    y2: 450
  };
```

Create your link using the data above (or your own) :

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data([thisData]) //data above
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style('stroke','black')
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
```

Position links :

```
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { console.log(d); return d.x1; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; });
```

All this needs is two points, `[X1,Y1] & [X2,Y2]` or in your case 15000 links. D3 will handle it all for you :))

```js
var svg = d3.select('#container').append('svg')
  .attr('width', 500)
  .attr('height', 500)
  //.append('g')
    
var thisData = {
    x1: 50,
    y1: 50,
    x2: 450,
    y2: 450
  };


 var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data([thisData])
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style('stroke','black')
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });
  //console.log(line);
  
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { console.log(d); return d.x1; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y1; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x2; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y2; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>


<div id='container'>

</div>
```

As long as your data looks like the above data or a set of points like so :

```
var thisData = { //first line
    x1: 50,
    y1: 50,
    x2: 450,
    y2: 450
  },
  { //second
    x1: 50,
    y1: 50,
    x2: 450,
    y2: 450
  },
  {//third
    x1: 50,
    y1: 50,
    x2: 450,
    y2: 450
  };
```

EDIT

Here is how you would show your data.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/odcyduvf/1/

I have set attached your data to a variable - 'thisData'.

Now to just draw the links you want to pass the links to D3 like above, like this :

```
.data(thisData.links)
```

Im not sure why you have x1,x2,x3,x4. If this is a path, for example, the points would be x1,y1 : x2,y2 : x3,y3 and so on then you can need to format your code so each individual link has x1,y1,x2,y2.

I would have shown all your data, but JSFiddle cant handle 135,000 lines of data :P

Comment: People generally write source and target, do I really need it? Because I cannot right source and target one by one for more than 10000+ nodes :)

Comment: you only use source and target if you have nodes attached, that way when you drag the nodes the links get updated. But in your case, as you said youre only drawing lines, in your dataset youll only need both start and end points x and y (with nodes this is the same as source.x, source.y, target.x, target.y). Did my answer manage to solve your problem ? Show me a dataset and ill show how it can be implemented in my code above

Comment: I emailed it to the address you shared on your profile. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @D.Ister added to answer, that solves your problem you asked yes ? Im unclear of what your end product will be as you have nodes too which youll have to implement the drawing of the nodes too :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply your code actually but I'll try, I guess I can add the nodes to the container that I need to create for lines too and write a new nodes code to make them work together. Is it possible?

Comment: I would create two variables, one for nodes and one for links. So var nodes = thisData.nodes, and var links = thisData.links. Apply the code i have given you to create the links and look up 'force layout D3' to see how to create the nodes. Will be simple :)

Comment: Okay I'll try and if I can't do it or get confused during the process, I will write here again. Thanks a lot

Comment: @D.Ister Check your email, I've replied